# Firebase storage and Invalid HTTP method/URL pair

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

When I try to fetch a firebase storage file using ReactReader, I get the following error:

```
{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair."
}
}
```

The code is making a request to https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/....

but that returns the error above.

Has anyone run into this issue?

Comment: Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, it’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. If the links break, it would invalidate the question.

Comment: I had the same problem, but solved it based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49367831

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error 400 when accessing firebase storage trying to get file url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42202370/error-400-when-accessing-firebase-storage-trying-to-get-file-url)

Answer (score 4):

I have got this problem, but no t for security reason, but when I would put a file in a subdir.

I was (with Postman) trying:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/*YOURBUCKET*.appspot.com/o/Test/test.pdf

And I got exactly this error ("message": "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair.").

The problem was the encoding of the url. It must be "encoded" and the "/" must the code, like so:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/*YOURBUCKET*.appspot.com/o/Test**%2F**test.pdf

No more erros.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, and it was actually a security feature.

As the security rules show, I shouldn't have access to the data unless I am **authenticated**.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```